# How to fix memory leak when calling ShowMessage?

Tags: delphi

I have code like this:

```
ShowMessage(Memo1.Lines.GetText);
```

Delphi is telling me there is a leak caused by that code:

[image: delphi message]

I try to fix it by using this code:

```pascal
var
  Message:string;
begin
  Message := Memo1.Lines.GetText;
  try
    ShowMessage(Message);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Message)
  end;
```

it's working somehow, however the program is automatically force-closed after that.

Is there a way to avoid the memory leak in this case?

Comment: Don't try to free a string. Strings are managed automatically.

Comment: @Olivier thanks for your answer. alright is there any way to avoid a message of memory leaks? i'm confused. or i should just ignore this message? thanks

Comment: Are you sure the leak is caused by `ShowMessage()`? It shouldn't.

Comment: What if you change `Memo1.Lines.GetText` to `Memo1.Lines.Text`?

Comment: @Olivier i'm not really sure. if i use specific value instead of Memo1.Lines.GetText it is not show me memory leak message.

Comment: @TomBrunberg okay i will give it a try

Comment: @TomBrunberg woooow it's working!!! i have no idea why but it is.. thanks sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`TStrings.GetText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.GetText) method returns a `PChar` pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer which must be freed with [`StrDispose()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrDispose), per the documentation:

> Allocates a text buffer and fills it with the value of the [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) property.
>
> ... The caller is responsible for freeing the returned value using the [`StrDispose`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrDispose) procedure.

You are not freeing that buffer after assigning it to your `string` variable, hence the memory leak, which has nothing to do with `ShowMessage()` itself.

To fix that, your code would need to look more like this instead:

```pascal
var
  Message: PChar;
begin
  Message := Memo1.Lines.GetText;
  try
    ShowMessage(Message);
  finally
    StrDispose(Message);
  end;
end;
```

A better option is to use the [`TStrings.Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) or [`TControl.Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Text) property instead of the `TStrings.GetText()` method. The compiler can manage the allocated memory for you:

```pascal
var
  Message: string;
begin
  Message := Memo1.Lines.Text;
  // or: Message := Memo1.Text;
  ShowMessage(Message);
end;
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i learn something new today.

Comment: Or just `ShowMessage(Memo1.Text);`

Comment: @StefanGlienke added